# gcloud app deploy is asking for a 'storage' attribute

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js app, specifying only the absolute minimum in the `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: nodejs8
```

gcloud gives me this:

```
MaxRetrialsException: last_result=(None, (<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'_Sections' object has no attribute 'storage'",), <traceback object at 0x106eca488>)), last_retrial=3, time_passed_ms=67,time_to_wait=0
```

No relevant reference I found mentions the `storage` attribute, and `MaxRetrials` sounds like a network problem, so no idea where to go from here.

gcloud version (no additional components installed):

```
Google Cloud SDK 217.0.0
bq 2.0.34
core 2018.09.17
gsutil 4.34
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "parrot-skill",
  "description": "Parrot skill",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "Pirim",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created a google storage bucket to be able to upload the files associated with the deployment?

> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets

Once you have a bucket you can specify it when you run gcloud deploy with the flag --bucket. If this argument is not specified, the application's default code bucket is used.

Reference:

> https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

Comment: Of course I didn't, who even reads those pesky prerequisites. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not finding the Storage dependency. Can you try deploying with the Cloud Storage dependency included in your package.json file as shown in [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage)?

```
"dependencies": {
"@google-cloud/storage": "1.6.0",
```